# How To Restore the records in mysql table which was deleted unfortunately

Tags: mysql, sql

I deleted records in a MySQL table two days ago. Can you please help me to get back these records. I don't know how to repair the MySDL table.

Please help me to get back the deleted data and mention some way to create a backup for my MySQL database.

Comment: you can't restore deleted data unless you have backup

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to lack a basic level of research.

Comment: You should have done a backup **before** you deleted the data. Now it's too late.

Comment: You can check the binary logs (if you have them) to see if you still have the insert transactions that were deleted - see this question for background http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394132/mysql-transaction-log. For a backup solution, try googling for "automysqlbackup".

Answer (score 4):

There's no "magical" way to restore deleted data, so :

[image]

To create a backup, you simply have to export the whole database in a file. This can be done easily with any database manager. Here is how to do it with PHPMyAdmin :

- Click on your database (left pane)
- Click on `Export` (top of the page)
- Click on `Go` for a quick and full export
- Keep the generated file in a safe place (ie. **not in your website folder**)